# Import SQLite database into Android emulator

Tags: android, sqlite, android-emulator

I've made an android application which needs to connect to a database. I've done making the database. Now my application is not working properly. My question is how can I import my created database into my android application that is running in android emulator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use adb push on the command line or DDMS import/export via eclispe to put the db on to your emulator

Here's a more details step by step: http://www.boringmonday.com/jc/2010/11/22/sqlite-database-on-your-android-emulator/

Comment: How can I check after pushing the database from eclipse if it's succesful?

Comment: You should be able to see your DB in data/data/<package_name>/databases/<database> from eclipse